# Setting up an alternative domain for an entire cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, openshift

I have an openshift cluster set up with a hosted application (Maximo Application Suite)

I'm attempting to set up an alternative domain for said cluster.

I want to keep the default routes and not change it, but have another domain that can be used in the same manner

Openshift by default have the .cluster_name.base_domain set up, I'm trying to change it so it can also use an alternative base_domain (cluster name too if possible, but it isn't an priority)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is your goal that everything currently accessible at `<something>.cluster_name.base_domain` is also accessible at `<something>.new_domain`? Note that for individual services, you can use whatever domain you want in your `Route` configuration.